# Is it possible to set a Variable with a Type which is a superclass uf a class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, abstract, extending-classes

More Informations:

EDIT: better sample:

I have a class in a Libary called UserAccount, its abstact. then i have some functionality like this in the library:

```
class UserAccountService
{
    public static UserAccount CreateUserAccount(String username, String password, String email)
    {
    UserAccount account = new UserAccount();
    account.Username = username;
    account.HashedPass = //Some crypting stuff with password
    account.Email = email;

    UserAccountRepository db = new UserAccountRepository();
    db.UserAccounts.Add(account);

    return account;
    }
}
```

Cuz this is a independent library the UserAccount has not all Propertys i want to use:

```
class ExtendedUserAccount : UserAccount
{
// define some additional methods and propertys
public Contact Contacts{get;set}// this property is only used in one application where i use the Library....
}
```

Then i want to do this:

```
ExtendedUserAccount newAccount = UserAccountService.CreateUserAccount(new UserAccount);
```

But this will not work. i now its not correct but i need something similar...

anyone has an idea??

Comment: Basic OOP - this can't work - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: `ExtendedUserAccount` is a _subclass_ of `UserAccount`, which is a _superclass_ of `ExtendedUserAccount`.

Comment: basicly i whant to dynamic extend the class UserAccount from the Library i use... i have the Soruce Code of this library so im thinking how i can change it to provide this i autonomy

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a code smell and you probably need to redesign your types... But anyway, this should work:

```
class UserAccountService
{
    public static TAccount CreateUserAccount<TAccount>(TAccount account)
          where TAccount : UserAccount, new()
    {
        //create new useraccount...
        return account;
    }
}
```

This generic method takes an instance of a type that *must* extend UserAccount (or be an UserAccount itself), and declare a parameterless constructor. This last restriction will allow you to do this: `TAccount account = new TAccount()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand the factory pattern

```
class UserAccountService
{
    // ctor with interfaces
    public IUserAccount CreateUserAccount()
    {
        // create instance
        return result;
    } 

    // ctor with generic
    public IUserAccount CreateUserAccount<T>() where T : UserAccount
    {
        var account = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        return account;
    } 
}

class ExtendedUserAccount : UserAccount
{
    // define some additional methods and propertys
}

class UserAccount : IUserAccount
{

}

internal interface IUserAccount
{
}
```

Comment: That's not the abstract factory pattern, nor the factory method pattern. You're using flags to tell the method what you want it to do - which is not a pattern.

Comment: you are right, most of the time you wan the factory to decide what to create and return. not with parameters / generics.

Comment: i improve my question that u can see what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear

Are this you conditions?

- UserAccountService & UserAccount are in Library A
- ExtendedUserAccount is, and only will be in Library B
- you can't/dont't want to edit library A

then the answer can be:
Make 1 entry point in Library B that make this possible

Comment: Almost: i can Edit library A but it should be still autonomly... What do you mean with a entry point ?